# Why does NFC not working for my app right after installation?

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I am using this [ndeftools](https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) library to communicate with the NFC hardware. It works fine except for one issue where right after the app is installed, the NFC doesn't seem to want to return anything. It makes the NFC sound like it is scanning the NFC tag, but nothing else happens. If I exit my app and scan the tag, the native NFC app is activated like usual. Once the device is restarted, NFC function is restored to my app from then on. I was wondering if anyone has ran into this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm including the code that I use to interface with the NFC library. For reading tags, I just use enableForegroundMode() and it works for the most part except for this one scenario right after install. Is there more I should be doing?

```
public class NfcHelper {

    private final String TAG = NfcHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    protected NfcAdapter m_NFCAdapter;
    protected PendingIntent m_NFCPendingIntent;

    private Context m_Context = null;

    public NfcHelper(Context p_Context) {
        m_Context = p_Context;

        m_NFCAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(m_Context);
        m_NFCPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(m_Context, 0, new Intent(m_Context, m_Context.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }

    public void disableForegroundMode() {
        Log.i(TAG, "disableForegroundMode");

        m_NFCAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch((Activity) m_Context);
    }

    public void enableForegroundMode() {
        Log.i(TAG, "enableForegroundMode");

        // foreground mode gives the current active application priority for reading scanned tags
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED); // filter for tags
        IntentFilter[] writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] {tagDetected};
        m_NFCAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch((Activity) m_Context, m_NFCPendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
    }

    public NfcAdapter getNFCAdapter() {
        return m_NFCAdapter;
    }

    public SimpleEntry<String, String> getNFCData(Intent p_intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getNFCData");

        byte[] arrTagSerial = null;
        String sTagSerial = "";
        String sTagContent = "";

        try {
            // check for NFC related actions
            if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(p_intent.getAction())) {
                arrTagSerial = p_intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
                sTagSerial = new BigInteger(arrTagSerial).toString(16);

                Parcelable[] messages = p_intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                if (messages != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Found " + messages.length + " NDEF messages");
                    //vibrate();

                    // parse to records
                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            List<Record> records = new Message((NdefMessage)messages[i]);

                            Log.d(TAG, "Found " + records.size() + " records in message " + i);

                            for(int k = 0; k < records.size(); k++) {
                                Log.d(TAG, " Record #" + k + " is of class " + records.get(k).getClass().getSimpleName());

                                Record record = records.get(k);
                                if (record instanceof TextRecord) {
                                    TextRecord txtrecord = (TextRecord) records.get(k);
                                    sTagContent = txtrecord.getText();
                                }
                                else if(record instanceof AndroidApplicationRecord) {
                                    AndroidApplicationRecord aar = (AndroidApplicationRecord)record;
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Package is " + aar.getPackageName());
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Problem parsing message", e);
                        }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new SimpleEntry<String, String>(sTagSerial, sTagContent);
    }

    public boolean writeText(String text, Intent intent) {
        Message message = new Message();
        org.ndeftools.wellknown.TextRecord textRecord = new org.ndeftools.wellknown.TextRecord();

        try {
            textRecord.setText(text);
            textRecord.setEncoding(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            textRecord.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

            message.add(textRecord);
            return writeMessage(message, intent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean writeMessage(Message message, Intent intent) {
        return writeMessage(message.getNdefMessage(), intent);
    }

    public boolean writeMessage(NdefMessage rawMessage, Intent intent) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        NdefFormatable format = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
        if (format != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Write unformatted tag");
            try {
                format.connect();
                format.format(rawMessage);

                //writeNdefSuccess();

                return true;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                //writeNdefFailed(e);
            } 
            finally {
                try {
                    format.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Cannot write unformatted tag");
        } 
        else {
            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Write formatted tag");

                    ndef.connect();
                    if (!ndef.isWritable()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Tag is not writeable");

                        //writeNdefNotWritable();

                        return false;
                    }

                    if (ndef.getMaxSize() < rawMessage.toByteArray().length) {
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                "Tag size is too small, have "
                                        + ndef.getMaxSize() + ", need "
                                        + rawMessage.toByteArray().length);

                        //writeNdefTooSmall(rawMessage.toByteArray().length, ndef.getMaxSize());

                        return false;
                    }
                    ndef.writeNdefMessage(rawMessage);

                    //writeNdefSuccess();

                    return true;
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    //writeNdefFailed(e);
                } 
                finally {
                    try {
                        ndef.close();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        // ignore
                    }
                }
            } 
            else {
                //writeNdefCannotWriteTech();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Cannot write formatted tag");
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int getMaxNdefSize(Intent intent) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        NdefFormatable format = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
        if (format != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Format tag with empty message");
            try {
                if (!format.isConnected()) {
                    format.connect();
                }
                format.format(new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[0]));
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem checking tag size", e);

                return -1;
            }
        }

        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef != null) {
            try {
                if (!ndef.isConnected()) {
                    ndef.connect();
                }

                if (!ndef.isWritable()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Capacity of non-writeable tag is zero");

                    //writeNdefNotWritable();

                    return 0;
                }

                int maxSize = ndef.getMaxSize();

                ndef.close();

                return maxSize;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem checking tag size", e);
            }
        } 
        else {
            //writeNdefCannotWriteTech();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Cannot get size of tag");

        return -1;
    }
}
```

EDIT2: Here is the code of my Activity that uses the NfcHelper:

```
private NfcHelper mNFC = new NfcHelper(this);

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    SimpleEntry<String, String> NFCData = null;

    // If intent from NFC tag scan
    if (intent.getAction() != null && 
        intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {  
        NFCData = mNFC.getNFCData(intent);

        // Do stuff with NFC data
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mNFC.enableForegroundMode();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() { 
    super.onResume();
    mNFC.disableForegroundMode();
}
```

Comment: It would help if you described what you are actually expecting (Should the app start but does not? Is the app started but does not receive NFC events? etc.) and what code you are actually using (just referencing to a repository with a couple of projects that you used as the basis for your app is not really helpful).

Comment: The app starts but does not received NFC events. Again, this only happens right after a fresh install. However, if you restart the device, the app will receive the NFC events as intend. I'm just wonder why exactly the NFC doesn't just work right after the fresh install.

If you need code, I pretty much followed this example, enabling the NFC foreground during onResume, ready to read NFC tags. 

https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/ndeftools-util/src/org/ndeftools/util/activity/NfcDetectorActivity.java

Comment: Did you call `startDetecting()` in your implementation of `NfcDetectorActivity`?

Comment: So what's the code of your activity then?

Comment: Added code. See Edit 2.